# How can I escape colons when jQuery loads json and there are colons in the json data?

Tags: jquery, json

So I am loading some Json that is transformed from RSS beforehand. This RSS has colons in it's namespaces and the conversion script doesn't strip them.

JQuery loads the json file fine, but when I try calling anything with the colon in it's name like

```
alert(data.rss.channel.item.kuler:themeItem.kuler:themeSwatches.kuler:swatch[0].kuler:swatchHexColor);
```

My javascript console throws an error. Any ideas? ( I already tried unicode )

Comment: Seems to me you have to fix your RSS to JSON converter then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON spec](http://www.json.org/) requires quotes around the names. Not strictly JavaScript's Object notation.

Answer (score 0):

If there are colons in the names, it's not JSON. The conversion script could always just quote them.  Probably it'd help if you'd post a sample of the converted RSS source.